# PHP Framework for extended CRUD operations with Community Functionality

Tags: php, frameworks, crud

I am currently in the process of deciding which PHP framework fits best for:

- MVC
- Generation and Customization of basic CRUD operations
- Good extendibility for additional functionality
- Good integration of AJAX requests
- Community functions are well integrated or integrable (Web 2.0)

I do not care if i have to code all that by myself, but decent and stable already coded solutions for the chosen platform/framework are surely welcome.

Currently i think that **Symfony2** is a good match, but maybe it is still too young. Also there are **Drupal** and **Joomla** with their many plugins, but i would prefer something else, because both are somehow restricting in the development process.

What do you think?

Comment: Depends what is the scale of your application, the symfony2 seems more like for EE solutions. Also you could try the Yii framework.

Comment: What do you mean by EE solutions?

Comment: Enterprise solutions, my mistake.

Comment: If you want a powerful framework, with an impressive API documentation and easy to learn, you can give a chance to Yii: yiiframework.com Maybe Symfony is smarter but I think Yii is sometimes more flexible.

Comment: Thanks jurka and cram1010 for the Yii hint. I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: I'm curious to know what would you think about http://agiletoolkit.org/ ? Regards.

Comment: Looks interesting. Do you have experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jurka says it depends.

Symfony2, like cakephp and many others, are frameworks focused on the MVC pattern and they offer a legion of usefull classes, methos, etc

On the other hand Joomla and Drupal are more a CMS, they can serve too as a framework but I think they are more oriented for content management. Here the question is define which "content" means.

I think the learning curve of a MVC framework is less than CMS (because a CMS have much more concepts and things probably you don't need to use) and, IMO, I think Symfony offers more flexibility over Drupal or Joomla in detriment on that you probably need to code more. With symfony you are responsible to create the controllers, routes, services, model and the views, but of course, you have a great degree of flexibility. With a CMS you need to follow "the rules" of the framework.

- MVC: symfony
- Generation and Customization of basic CRUD operations: symfony + Doctrine or propel
- Good extendibility for additional functionality: both symfony or drupal, it depens on your knowlege and learning curve.
- Good integration of AJAX requests: I use symfony for a REST API without problems

What application you plan to create?
If it is some kind of web page I prefer Symfony.
If it is some forum, blog, or something I can add "content" I prefer Drupal.
If it is implementing a REST API I prefer symfony.

Hope it can clarify a bit.

Comment: Thanks neil, that's my opinion too. The application i am planning to create is some sort of web application which enables users to enter, view, rate, tag and comment content. Basicly what "Web 2.0" is about. I think i have to go the framework way and not the CMS way.